# In Xcode 4 which is the better app Window based or view based?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am very new to iOS development. I am going to start a new project which is mostly related to to the database. Can you suggest what should I start from Window or view based app?

Comment: 'better' is a matter of application, and it's got nothing to do with the IDE (Xcode). Did you read any tutorials or something similar?

Comment: Yes I have read some tutorials(video).

Answer (score 0):

A view-based app only have one view, and includes a nib. However, window based app don't include a nib or a view, it's for add your own view.
I would chose view-based

Answer (score 0):

1.There is no such difference in both

In View Based app you will get a default view controller in window.

In Window Based app you will not get anything by default already added in window, you have to add your own view.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you have to make ViewController if you make project using window based. 
Make your project using window based and View based. and compare both. So you can find what is different.

and iOS can have many view on only one window.

Answer (score 0):

They're used for different things. Neither is better than the other.

If you're a total rookie, I'd go with View based. It comes wired up with more stuff for you by default, and lets you work on your app's functionality rather than the details of getting stuff on the screen. It also limits you in ways that Window based doesn't, but for your level that's probably a good thing.